# How to show excel using jsp avoiding "No input source supplied to the exporter".?

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports

I have written some code to show excel in a website.

But I'm getting this exception

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: No input source
>   supplied to the exporter.

## My code

**import in jsp**

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.HashMap"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Map"%>
<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream"%>
<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer"%>
<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.*"%>
```

**jsp code to export to excel**

```
        <%
        Connection conn = null;
        String no1 = request.getParameter("no1");
        String no2 = request.getParameter("no2");

        System.out.println("get value " + no1 + " " +no2);
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ams2"
                                                ,"root","passwd1234");
            File reportFile = new File (application.getRealPath("//jasper//report//Blank_A4_2.jasper"));
            Map parameters = new HashMap();

            parameters.put("no1",no1);
            parameters.put("no2",no2);
            System.out.println("123 "+parameters);

            ByteArrayOutputStream xlsReport = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, xlsReport);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE, "C:\\");
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "sample.xls");
            exporter.exportReport();

            byte bytes[] = new byte[10];
            bytes = xlsReport.toByteArray();
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

            response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
            xlsReport.close();
            ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
            outStream.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            out.println("Error " + ex);
        }
    %>
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using a very old version of JasperReports, you are using deprecated methods and most importantly you are not passing the `JasperPrint` to the exporter.

> No input source supplied to the exporter.

You need to **fill the report**, using the `JasperFillManager.fillReport`

**Example code (jasper report v5 or above)**

```
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(new FileInputStream(reportFile));
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperDesign, parameters, conn);

JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint)); //The JasperPrint, filled report
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(xlsReport)); //Your ByteArrayOutputStream 

SimpleXlsReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
configuration.setOnePagePerSheet(true);
configuration.setDetectCellType(true);
configuration.set //The other properties you like to set
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);

exporter.exportReport();
```

Comment: I need import other or just add JasperFillManager.fillReport in my code?

Comment: Check out my example follow the code, it should be fairly clear.